# Moto G Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) pairing issue

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have created sample application to work with Glucose meter.
Sample application has options to pair , connect and get data from meter etc.
I am using Google BLE API for this purpose.

**Issue:**

1. Almost 70% of the time, Moto G never discovers the glucose meter via BLE scan.
2. If it discovers and if sample application tries to pair , pairing fails.
3. For very few times sample application successfully paired with glucose meter. after that if application try to fetch the data from glucose meter, meter gets unpaired from Moto G in between.

Same issue is observed when we tried to pair glucose meter with standard Bluetooth pairing procedure.
We have tried 4-5 different glucose meters but the issue remains same. 
Sample application works with different other devices like Samsung Galaxy S5, HTC ONE, Samsung Note II & III, LG G2 etc.

Is there any known BLE issue in Moto G?
How to solve above issue?

**Setup:**

•   Moto G - android version 4.4.2

•   Eclipse Indigo.

I am giving the log of my sample application for the reference.

```
05-09 11:20:14.353: D/-GlucoseProfileHelper-9(11851): Device Connected.
05-09 11:20:14.354: I/-GlucoseProfileHelperGoogle-9(11851): Pairing Callback onDeviceConnected
05-09 11:20:14.356: I/-TimeOutThread(11851): resetTimer
05-09 11:20:14.436: I/-GoogleGatt-9(11851): IN onDescriptorWrite
05-09 11:20:14.437: I/-TimeOutThread(11851): resetTimer
05-09 11:20:14.439: I/-GoogleGatt-9(11851): characteristic=00002a18-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, status = 5
05-09 11:20:14.541: V/-BleConnectionManager-9(11851): android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED
05-09 11:20:14.543: E/-BleConnectionManager-9(11851): BOND STATE CHANGE00:11:22:33:44:55
05-09 11:20:14.555: I/-BtEventReceiver-9(11851): Device : 00:11:22:33:44:55
05-09 11:20:14.555: I/-BtEventReceiver-9(11851): Previous Bond State =(BOND_NONE)
05-09 11:20:14.555: I/-BtEventReceiver-9(11851): current state :(BOND_BONDING)
05-09 11:20:44.081: D/-GoogleTSGattCallback-9(11851): onConnectionStateChange  00:11:22:33:44:55 old status = 0, New state = disconnected
05-09 11:20:44.104: I/-GoogleGatt-9(11851): onConnectionStateChange - state = 0, Status = 0
05-09 11:20:44.104: D/-Profile-9(11851): Device disconnected
05-09 11:20:44.104: I/-GlucoseProfileHelperGoogle-9(11851): Pairing Callback onDeviceDisconnected
05-09 11:20:44.105: I/-GlucoseProfileHelper-9(11851): Pairing Callback - sending Constants.ACTION_BLE_PAIRING_INITIATION_FAILED broadcast
05-09 11:20:44.137: V/-BleConnectionManager-9(11851): android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED
05-09 11:20:44.138: E/-BleConnectionManager-9(11851): BOND STATE CHANGE00:11:22:33:44:55
05-09 11:20:44.180: I/-BleConnectionManager-9(11851): Pairing Finished
05-09 11:20:44.181: I/-BleConnectionManager-9(11851): Started - moveToNextStateToPairing - BEGIN
05-09 11:20:44.184: I/-BtEventReceiver-9(11851): Device : 00:11:22:33:44:55
05-09 11:20:44.184: I/-BtEventReceiver-9(11851): Previous Bond State =(BOND_BONDING)
05-09 11:20:44.184: I/-BtEventReceiver-9(11851): current state :(BOND_NONE)
05-09 11:20:44.184: V/-BleConnectionManager-9(11851): com.ble.action.ble_pairing_initiation_faied
05-09 11:20:44.688: I/-TimeOutThread(11851): Thread is stopped at counter =56
05-09 11:20:44.724: I/-TimeOutThread(11851): Thread is stopped at counter =4
05-09 11:20:45.181: I/-BleConnectionManager-9(11851): Moving to Scan state
05-09 11:20:45.181: I/-BleScanner-9(11851): startDeviceScan
05-09 11:20:45.182: I/-BleScanner-9(11851): Init Adapter retValue = true
05-09 11:20:45.182: I/-BleConnectionManager-state-9(11851): Device - NULL , State - Scanning
05-09 11:20:45.182: W/-BleConnectionManager-9(11851): Started - moveToNextStateToPairing - END
05-09 11:20:45.184: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): BleBroadcastReceiver
05-09 11:20:45.186: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): startBluetoothDiscovery called.
05-09 11:20:45.201: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): ACTION_BLE_DISCOVERY_STARTEDo.?@420a11c8
05-09 11:20:57.213: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): ACTION_BLE_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.
05-09 11:20:57.213: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): startBluetoothDiscovery called.
05-09 11:20:57.220: I/-GoogleBleAdapter-9(11851): Timer canceled
05-09 11:20:57.223: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): ACTION_BLE_DISCOVERY_STARTEDo.?@420a11c8
05-09 11:20:57.223: I/-BleBroadcastReceiver-ScanMonitorThread-9(11851): Monitor Thread Interrupted
05-09 11:21:02.355: I/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851):  device Found -> address ->00:11:22:33:44:55, Bonded state : Not bonded
05-09 11:21:09.225: I/-GoogleBleAdapter-9(11851): Timer canceled
05-09 11:21:09.226: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): ACTION_BLE_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.
05-09 11:21:09.226: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): startBluetoothDiscovery called.
05-09 11:21:09.230: I/-BleBroadcastReceiver-ScanMonitorThread-9(11851): Monitor Thread Interrupted
05-09 11:21:09.231: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): ACTION_BLE_DISCOVERY_STARTEDo.?@420a11c8
05-09 11:21:09.258: I/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851):  device Found -> address ->00:11:22:33:44:55, Bonded state : Not bonded
05-09 11:21:21.252: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): ACTION_BLE_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.
05-09 11:21:21.252: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): startBluetoothDiscovery called.
05-09 11:21:21.258: I/-GoogleBleAdapter-9(11851): Timer canceled
05-09 11:21:21.260: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): ACTION_BLE_DISCOVERY_STARTEDo.?@420a11c8
05-09 11:21:21.261: I/-BleBroadcastReceiver-ScanMonitorThread-9(11851): Monitor Thread Interrupted
05-09 11:21:21.296: I/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851):  device Found -> address ->00:11:22:33:44:55, Bonded state : Not bonded
05-09 11:21:33.269: D/-BleBroadcastReceiver-9(11851): ACTION_BLE_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.
```

Comment: I experience a similar issue. Guess the Moto G does not properly support bonding. The state BOND_BONDED is never reached. (And therefore the first read leads to a disconnect.)